# Givens method for sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, matrix

I have a (very) large sparse matrix in CSC form and I'm supposed to factorize it. I've read that between Givens and Householder transformations, Givens is better for a sparse matrix. The problem is that I don't really know how I should do it (everything's fine for a full matrix, but now all I have are three vectors).

I don't want to use built-in Matlab functions.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp! I take it you want to perform a QR decomposition? Are you working in MATLAB or in another language? Is there a particular reason you don't want to use built-in MATLAB functions?

Comment: Thank you. Yes. I'm working in MATLAB. It's part of a homework, I have to implement a function that does that myself.